# autocomplete taking time to render for first time

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete, bing-api

I have an input field where i am searching for locations through bing api.

```
this.addressForm
  .get('queryField')
  .valueChanges.debounceTime(100)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(query => this.onChangeSearch(query))
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

**Note:**

When we load the app, for the *First time* when i enter only **1 character** in the field, its taking couple of seconds to render the view. The API response is fine, but the list gets populated after couple of seconds.

This does not happen from second time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change detection - here's the fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete-7ryhdv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

These are the lines:

```
  constructor(
    private bingApiLoader: BingApiLoaderService,
    private fg: FormBuilder,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef <- ADD THIS
  ) {}

...

    this.manager.getSuggestions(search, res => {
      this.countries = res.map(r => {
        return {
          formattedSuggestion: r.formattedSuggestion,
          address: r.address
        };
      });
      this.results = this.countries;
      this.ref.detectChanges(); <- AND THIS
    });
```

In reality, you should be using observables for everything (instead of instance members) and your template should just be subscribing to them.

Here's an example of what I mean. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k47m7k

It uses a package I wrote a long time ago (ignore the package itself) but just pay attention to how there are no instance members and all the template does is subscribe to observables with [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

I've seen a lot of very experienced angular devs do exactly what the OP has done regarding **stateful components*** - just create some instance members, call `detectChanges()` when they feel like they have to. But in reality, **when you are dealing with a stateful component**, your template should just be subscribing to observables.

**A stateful component is a component that has created some sort of data that it will pass on to child components.*

Comment: Thanks Adam! this works, Is this because the code is not running in angular zone. What i am not understanding is why its taking a bit to render...

Comment: It doesnt *take a bit to render*. It simply doesn't know that it needs to render. The next time you hit a keystroke it runs change detection and understands there's changes from the last time and renders them. If I'm not mistaken, your original code is actually going to always be one render behind where it should be.

Comment: Will creating new objects not work? instead of changeDetection?

Comment: @ShankarGuru that's correct. Sometimes people misunderstand and think that's how it does work because the new object they create happens before a change detection cycle runs so it "looks" right (not the case for you). Everything's an observable and async pipe in the templates keeps data flowing through your application nice and easy, keeps it very testable, and you don't have to do a bunch of changeDetection hacks.